# Double-NAT. Need help in Port Forwarding

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, nat

Setup -

I have a PPPoE Internet connection where my main router A (TP-Link Archer C20 AC750 dual band) is connected to the PPPoE device provided by my ISP through ethernet over WAN port. I have also connected another router B (Mi Router 3C) to router A through wifi and router B acts as wifi extender. DHCP is only enabled on ROUTER A. My main PC is connected directly to ROUTER A through a LAN cable. Rest of my devices connects through wifi to either of the two routers. Since its a PPPoE connection hence I have a dynamic Ip which I have resolved to a hostname using no-ip running on my ROUTER A (Inbuilt functionality)

I read somewhere that I am in a double-NAT situation hence I need to ask my ISP to open ports for me which they did on their end(I got an email from them). Now, when I am running qbittorent and if I want to access its webUI I goto my virtual server section under port forwading and input the Local IP of my PC connected directly to router A through LAN and then one of the ports which my ISP forwarded for me on their end. Also, I enable DMZ for PC. In order to access webUI I google what is my ip and paste public IP:port in the address bar. The port is the one forwarded by my isp and mentioned both in virtual server section and in qbittorent webUI section. After all this, I still cannot seem to access the webUI over the internet.

Comment: There are several kinds of "double-NAT" situations. Yours does not appear to be ISP-related at all, as _you_ have the two routers.

Comment: Do you have a firewall enabled on your PC if so is the qbittorent webUI port open to external connections?

Comment: Yes in outbound connections section of firewall I have opened the port.

Comment: @grawity Yeah as it turns out I am not in double-NAT situation.